# How to get players scores for the current week

Tags: php

I've been left some code to try and figure out, which is..

```
 public function scoreboard($ttime, $numb = 10) {    

    if ($ttime == "day") { $timesearch = $this->myTime - 86400; }   

    if ($ttime == "week") { $timesearch = $this->myTime - 604800; }

    if ($ttime == "month") { $timesearch = $this->myTime - 18144000; }

    if ($ttime == "hiscore") { $timesearch = $this->myTime - 1000000000; }

    //get top 10 ------------------   

    return @mysql_query("SELECT uid, name, score, FROM table WHERE scoredate>$timesearch ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT $numb");   

  }
```

What I need is to get the players score for the current week, I.e the actual week in which the score was created (based on server date), but I think that code doesn't do that? it seems to take the current date and just go back 7 days?

Comment: What's the field type of `scoredate`? int? datetime?

Answer (score 1):

If your week starts on a Monday, use

```
<?php

if (date('N') == '1')
    $time = strtotime('today');
else
    $time = strtotime('last monday');

$query = sprintf('SELECT uid, name, score, FROM table WHERE scoredate>"%s" ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT %d', date('Y-m-d', $time) . ' 00:00:00', $numb);
```